# Number of foreigners in the Waffen-SS and Wehrmacht during WWII

Tags: world-war-two, military

During World War II, thousands of non-German men fought in the *Waffen*-SS and in the *Wehrmacht*. People from all Europe, volunteers from neutral and occupied countries and enemy prisoners. Even Russian and Arab units existed.

How many were there? It would be interesting to know the numbers grouped by country.

Comment: It depends, are you asking about the whole Wehrmacht or only the Waffen-SS?

Comment: The Wikipedia page [Waffen-SS foreign volunteers and conscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffen-SS_foreign_volunteers_and_conscripts) seems to cover this quite well although I don't see Arabs mentioned. Also, have a look at [Wehrmacht foreign volunteers and conscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehrmacht_foreign_volunteers_and_conscripts).

Comment: I expect that the answer will be a "social sciences number" with lots of qualifiers and unknowns. There were ethnic Germans in central Europe who got both citizenship and their draft papers when the Wehrmacht arrived. How do you count them? There were non-Germans in military coats who were not, technically, soldiers.

Comment: According to Russian-language sources there were about 1 million Soviet citizens (not only Russian but other nationalities as well) in the German army overall. Most of them were so called Hiwis (volunteer helpers). SS units formed from Soviet citizens were much smaller than this.

Comment: @AlexJ.: Faulty question. The Waffen-SS was *not part of the Wehrmacht*. They were placed under strategic control of the OKW (high command), but a separate organization. So "the whole Wehrmacht or only the Waffen-SS" does not make sense.

Comment: @DevSolar I already knew that, but he mentioned both in his original question, so I asked for the sake of precision. However I did phrase it wrongly or ambiguously.

Comment: @AlexJ.: Fair enough. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

this is way better and is from @ Lars Bosteen =  [better list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffen-SS_foreign_volunteers_and_conscripts)

As I know there were at least 1 Flanders unit of the SS and, if I believe right, 1 motorized SS division of the Dutch, with 2 infantry divisions. There were also units deployed into normal SS divisions and I don't think there are any actual numbers of volunteers.

There was also a Georgiërs legion deployed on the island of the Texel. They actually mutinied the German island and almost captured Texel but the Germans recaptured the island and try to find all the Georgiërs. This happened from 6th April and ended around end April/start of May. The last fighting on the island was the 20th May when the Canadians captured the island. The Germans had surrendered in the Netherlands 2 weeks earlier on the 5th of May.

Comment: Have you seen the comment by Lars Bosteen? Which does link to a rather extensive list of nationalities and numbers?

Comment: nope have not read the comments to well and that looks very wel made

Comment: There were no 3 Dutch divisions. There was a single combined Dutch/Belgian division, several (I think 2) French divisions, one or two Swedish ones, and smaller units from countries like Denmark and Norway.